# Angle between two vectors, when you don't know one constant

Tags: vector-spaces

I have two airplanes

Airplane 1 has the equation $3i-4j + p(-2i+3+1)$, airplane two has the equation $(2i, -5j + 8k) + p(-i+2j+ak)$. The angle between airplane one and airplane two is **40** degrees. I need to find the two values for $a$. I know that $a \times b \times \cos\theta$ is 40 but I don't know how to proceed. I have been trying to solve this for about 4 hours now, and I am beginning to lose hope.

Comment: Is this $$3i-4j+p(2i+3j+k)$$?

Comment: yes, except that there's minus in front of 2i

Answer (score 2):

From the formulae for the movement of both airplanes you can read their velocities (up to a scaling factor, but the scale won't matter for the angle):
$$ \vec v_1 = -2\vec i + 3\vec j+ \vec k$$
$$ \vec v_2 = -\vec i + 2\vec j +a \vec  k$$ 
You can calculate
$$ |\vec v_1| = \sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2+1^2} = \sqrt{14}$$
$$ |\vec v_2| = \sqrt{(-1)^2+2^2+a^2} = \sqrt{5 +a^2}$$
$$ \vec v_1\cdot \vec v_2 = (-2)\cdot (-1)+3\cdot 2 + 1\cdot a = 8+a$$
You have then an equation
$$ 8+a = \sqrt{14} \sqrt{5 +a^2} \cos(40^\circ)$$
From this you are able to find the value of $a$.

Comment: Thank you, but this is actually the step where I got stuck :/ I don't understand how to get a in a form where you can get two different values of a

Comment: @JoannaSeppänen Square both sides then it is a quadratic in $a$.

Comment: @JoannaSeppänen What Peter said.